# Do I need Turkish Visa for transit if going from Sabiha Gokcen International Airport?

Tags: transit-visas, turkey, saudi-citizens

I want to travel from KSA to Greece via Pegasus airlines. Layover will be in Sabiha Gokcen International Airport. Is it required to have

Comment: We can’t answer without knowing your citizenship

Comment: My citizenship is Saudi

Answer (score 1):

No if you won't leave the transit lounge

[source](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/frequently-asked-questions.en.mfa)